# Strict Mode in React ... why <React.StrictMode> repeat run code two times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strict

When I use `<React.StrictMode>`
in

`ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root'));`

and the App.js is

```
render() {
  console.log('enter render')
return(<React.Fragment>
                <h1>HI</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
)}}
```

after run project console show

> enter render

2 times

if I delete  `<React.StrictMode>` then I saw in the consol

> enter render

for one time

why did this happen?

Comment: please check the duplicate post

Comment: For some internal reason probably only the React core developers know, and it honestly doesn't _matter_.

React can decide to call your `render()` function in the middle of the night, and it shouldn't matter, since `render()` should be a pure function that just returns markup.